# Когда необходимо использовать модификатор internal?

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, в чем смысл использования данного модификатора?

Со стороны кажется, что это какой-то костыль, который нарушает принципы открытости/закрытости...

Comment: смысл его написан в документации, что именно вам там не понятно или вызывает затруднения?

Comment: `private` - "доступно только мне", `protected` - "доступно мне и моим детям", `internal` - "доступно мне и моим соседям", `public` - "доступно мне и всем вокруг"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Со стороны кажется, что это какой-то костыль, который нарушает принципы открытости/закрытости...

Нет, не нарушает, это следующий уровень - разделение кодовой базы на модули, а не просто классы и структуры (далее по тексту - типы). `internal` виден в пределах одной сборки, что дает возможность скрыть типы и их члены, которые должны быть публичными, с точки зрения ООП, но не должны быть доступны конечному потребителю сборки. Это важно при разработке библиотек и фреймворков, т.к. для внутренних нужд могут требоваться дополнительные служебные типы или члены публичных типов, например особый конструктор или метод использующие служебный тип. К тому же, модификаторы `private` и `protected` применяются только к членам типа. Ими можно пометить тип, но только если этот тип является вложенным в другой тип, что не решает проблему. Таким образом, без `internal`, у вас нет ни одного варианта скрыть служебные типы от конечного потребителя, которому не нужно знать детали внутреннего взаимодействия между компонентами сборки так же, как ему не нужно знать детали реализации классов сборки.

Да, некоторая путаница присутствует, но ни какого нарушения принципов нет, просто это принципы разных уровней.

Конечно, если вы не занимаетесь разработкой библиотек или фреймворков, которые могут/будут распространяться отдельно от вашего приложения, скорее всего, этот модификатор вам не потребуется.

Comment: ну наверное имеет смысл добавить ссылку на [доку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal), хотя там, в приципе, тож самое написано.

Comment: @tym32167 ну да, тоже самое, только много нужных слов опущены, как очевидные. С одной стороны порог входа у .net сравнительно невысокий, с другой - документация, местами, написана в стиле "ну это же очевидно". Но это все равно лучше чем ее отсутствие.